# How to implement weighted data property in protege 4

Tags: properties, ontology, protege, weighted, reification

I am implementing an ontology to check for semantic similarity between individuals of different classes of animals. Say Cow is exactly similar to Cow and nearly similar to buffalo/bull etc. but cow is not similar to dog. i have different data properties that i want to associate weight or degree. Eg for cow, isDomestic property has weight 90 (i.e in 90% cases a cow would be kept as domestic animal) but isSecurity will have weight 0 i.e in no case a cow is kept for security. while Dog isDometic is again 90, but Dog isSecurity will have value say 70 or more. Thats how cow and dog would not be similar.

i have came across RDF reification but i need to implement it in Protege and then use OWL api to reason and check for semantic similarity of individuals.

Any hint or guidance will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You won't be able to use RDF reification in Protege.  Protege is an *OWL tool*, and it's only a useful coincidence (by design) that OWL can be *serialized* as RDF.  I think what you mean end up needing is n-ary relations.  See, e.g., [Defining N-ary Relations on the Semantic Web](http://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-n-aryRelations/).

Comment: And, by the way, cattle can be pretty loud and dangerous.  You might give them a non-zero security measure.

Comment: N-ary Relations was exactly i was looking for "Example 1" of the link you suggested to be specific. But does OWL API has ability to query such a complex ontology at present?

Comment: If you can represent something in OWL, you can use the OWL API manipulate it.  And if there are common patterns that arise, you can implement a layer over it to make things easier.  At the moment, though, it's not really specific enough to ask whether OWL API has the ability;  do you have a specific use case that you're having trouble with?